# How to integrate react native component into the native app?

Tags: react-native

I used to see lots of articles about native modules inside RN apps, but very few about RN inside native project. Let's say we have a project, in which we want to add a single screen fully developed using RN. As far as i know, instagram have something like this. I have read [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) about this, but it left too many questions. Does anybody know the good step-by-step implementation guide?

**Mostly, i'm interested in:**

1. What is the structure. Do i really need to move all the project inside /ios and /android folder, wrapping the whole project? What if the project have separate repositories for both platforms?
2. Do native developers need to install node environment in order to continue working on the project, installing node_modules and staff?
3. How much is the influence on the app size?

**UPDATE: 07.20.2021**
I'm still not able to run an RN screen inside native projects. The docs i told about before doesn't contain actual info, steps are not properly described, and even writing exactly as they told, the project still cannot run and crash as fast as i change activity to RN one.

Comment: Any progress on that?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points related to the questions that you have which might help you.

1. No, You don't need to move the whole native code to the /android and /ios directory.
2. Yes if you are about to open the RN screen from the native app you should have set up the react-native environment properly.
3. The app size might increase as there is a bridge created with javascript and native code. but you should have a choice to upload the .aab bundle file which helps you to provide the platform-specific builds to the users.

Comment: 1. But how do i even implement rn component without /ios, /android folder then?

Comment: For this you might have to create native components in your native project and import it in react native code as you are already in the native code that means for android you are already in android folder.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm really confused. I don't have a react native code yet, only ios and android projects, and i want to add  a screen with react native code there. Why do i have to "create native component and import it in react native code", if i do not want any native imports.
Imagine i have an "Example" native project.
And "RNSomeComponent". So, how i can use RNSomeComponent inside Example, without wrapping whole Example project in /ios folder?

Comment: you simply have to open your ios native project and follow the https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps documentation to integrate react native in native code and then you can design the screen with react and javascript.

Comment: But the tutorial says "To ensure a smooth experience, create a new folder for your integrated React Native project, then copy your existing iOS project to a /ios subfolder."

Comment: Yes, We also can implement like this.